# Number raised to a power enclosed in parenthesis and raised to a power

Tags: math-mode

How can I write this expression using LaTeX?

`(2^2)^x+1`
that reads as
in parenthesis
2 raised to 2, close parenthesis, and then raised to a binomial as `x+1`.

I am struggling with this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried $(2^2)^{x+1}$? Use braces (curly brackets) to delimit arguments to TeX macros and operators that consist of more than a single character.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**

```
(2^{2})^{x+1}
```

**Extended answer**

In the official LaTeX manual you'll not find instances of code similar to `2^2`, but always in the style `2^{2}`; the same for subscripts.

This is not only for uniformity, but mainly to avoid doubts such as yours.

You want to specify what's the superscript and if you type

```
2^x+1
```

TeX will just take `x` as the exponent: what else could it do? It cannot read your mind.

True, a possibility for specifying “two to the power 2, plus one” might have been

```
2^2 +1
```

with a space. However Knuth decided that spaces in math formulas are *always* ignored; moreover, `2^2 +1` would be ambiguous anyway.

So the right syntax is

```
(2^{2})^{x+1}
```

The single token exponent inside the parentheses *can* also be `2^2`, but leave this for when you'll be more experienced.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes, it does work well like that. Excellent!.

Answer (score 5):

Try (similarly as is suggested in @Gernot comment):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
$\bigl(2^2\bigr)^{x+1}$
\end{document}
```

[image]